# Insert -> select and add my column

Tags: sql

how i can added my values in column
for example

t1

```
 id | name | surname | mycolumn
 1  | f    | g       |
 +++|++++++|+++++++++|++++++++++
```

and t2

```
 u_id | u_name | u_surname
   1  | 2f     | 2g
 +++++|++++++++|+++++++++++
```

:)
so, query

```
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT (u_name,u_surname) FROM t2 WHERE u_id = 1
```

how set value `mycolumn`, in my variable?

Comment: Do you want to `update` the columns in `table t1` based on id in `table t2`?

Comment: i think the query is itself wrong

Comment: will you explain what you want??

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question: you are trying to insert values into a table from another table but they have different column names and different column count. In that case, you can simply rename the columns of the second table since you are querying the result, but you will need a third column, for that use NULL if you don't have a value yet

```
INSERT INTO t1 
    SELECT u_id id,u_name name,u_surname surname, null mycolumn 
        FROM t2 WHERE u_id = 1
```

Comment: I forgot about the id/u_id so I modified the query. Check now